# 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLException': ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. (SYS.DBMS_XMLSAVE)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, permissions, java

I have this function (**written [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2853285548502) by someone**), placed in the package `ENVER.ENCODING_VERIFIER`:

```
FUNCTION loadxml_table (p_owner IN VARCHAR2, p_tablename IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2, p_tmpClob IN NUMBER) RETURN number
IS

  v_ctx dbms_xmlsave.ctxType;
  v_rows number := -1;

BEGIN

  for c1 in (select theclob
               from enver.tmp_xml_clob
              where id = p_tmpClob) loop

    v_ctx := dbms_xmlsave.newContext(upper(p_owner || '.' || p_tableName));
    dbms_xmlsave.setDateFormat(v_ctx, p_format);

    v_rows := dbms_xmlsave.insertxml(v_ctx, c1.theclob);
    dbms_xmlsave.closeContext(v_ctx);

    delete from enver.tmp_xml_clob
     where id = p_tmpclob;
  end loop;

  return v_rows;

END loadxml_table;

END;
```

In the table: `tmp_xml_clob`, column: `theclob` (`id=1`), I have this record:

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <IMAGE></IMAGE>
  <MESSAGE>a</MESSAGE>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

The structure of `MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE` table is like the following:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID                                                 NUMBER(38)
IMAGE                                              BLOB
MESSAGE                                            VARCHAR2(10)
```

When I call it from SQLPLUS logged as user ENVER (but it give me the same error if I call it from Java method, as explained in the link to the page I have included above):

```
declare
     x number;
     begin
     x := enver.encoding_verifier.loadxml_table('MYSCHEMA', 'MYTABLE', 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss', 1);
     end;
/
```

Unfortunately, this error is returned:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLException:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
' encountered during processing ROW element 1.  All prior XML row changes were
rolled back. in the XML document.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLSAVE", line 115
ORA-06512: at "ENVER.ENCODING_VERIFIER", line 179
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

**The error is generated by the line**:

```
v_rows := dbms_xmlsave.insertxml(v_ctx, c1.theclob);
```

In the trace file I have this message:

```
Exception in thread "Root Thread" oracle.xml.sql.OracleXMLSQLException: 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
' encountered during processing ROW element 1.  All prior XML row changes were rolled back. in the XML document.
        at oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave.saveXML(OracleXMLSave.java:2568)
        at oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLSave.insertXML(OracleXMLSave.java:1521)
        at oracle.xml.sql.dml.OracleXMLStaticSave.insertXML(OracleXMLStaticSave.java:466)
```

I don't know what privileges refers to the error. The user ENVER have all privileges in any of these tables. I tried to perform the same function as SYS, but nothing.

I have already granted execute on `DBMS_XMLSAVE` to `ENVER`, but it still does not work.

What could be the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Does `ENVER` have privs on `MYSCHEMA`?  Is that the real schema name? You're better off not bothering hiding the real names. Only causes confusion

Comment: Sorry, I thought the opposite. Anyway, that is my fault, I made a stupid mistake of not giving the priv "insert any table" to ENVER :/.
You made me think about this. Thanks.